# Random Freezing on Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Tags: 20.04, freeze

I guess I *sort of* solved this one, but I'm still having troubles... let me explain

I recently installed ubuntu MATE on my main computer, after having good experiences on my laptop.
It ran perfectly fine for ~1 month with no issue. After that I began experiencing freezing about every hour. This was partially solved by putting "iommu=pt" into my GRUB boot parameters. Now the freezing happens much less often, about every 10 or so hours.
I haven't found any significant errors in var/log/syslog and dmesg finds no errors either.

The only answer I found to this exact question related to NVIDIA drivers conflicting. I'm running:

Radeon RX 480 4GB

Ryzen 5 1600x

8GB DDR4 2400

and Ubuntu is installed on my 1tb WD SSD (not NVMe)

Another note, the mouse is not frozen when my system freezes, but my keyboard doesn't work.

One more thing, The frozen screen eventually goes black with no response, only fix is to hard reset the machine.

UPDATE:
I've run Memtest86 free and it returned with no errors.
so I can rule out bad memory as the culprit.

UPDATE 2:
I'm trying this on GNOME (I was running on MATE before), I'll update later if it freezes.

Comment: I had a bit similar issue on Ubuntu MATE 18.04, only the freezing happened usually in two situations: a) when using LibreOffice b) after a screen saver did activate while RDP session to another machine (using FreeRDP) was active. I sometimes was able to switch to text console and see an error about GPU Lockup in Nouveau graphics driver (I had an old NVIDIA card that isn't supported anymore by proprietary drivers, so I had to use Nouveau). I was unable to solve the issue, I replaced the graphics card with one supported by NVIDIA drivers and installed regular 20.04 (not MATE).

Comment: i'm not using nouveau, other than that, the only reason it locks up is screensavers maybe? i should have screensavers turned off...